# html tables - filling dynamic space

Tags: html, html-table

I have a web page with a set of nested tables to keep the scenario simple I have two columns, the right column is dynamic, the height expands and contracts with the content being displayed. (I am using a PHP backend but for the purpose of the question the layout is html).

The left column contains some static content of a fixed height the remaining content is filled with a block of colour to match the style of the page auto expanding to match the right hand column.

My question - my static content usually fills the space , however I sometimes end up with big block of colour, is there a way to put  some meaningful content in this space when the cell is for example bigger than XXX pixels in height. I suppose I am asking is there a way to detect the height and fill it accordingly. i.e. if I have the space available put a Google ad in

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript.

You can get the height of parent and then height of child which is not occupying parent completely and get the difference.